# Strongly Connected Components

Tags: java, algorithm, strongly-connected-graph

I got a problem, my output is not correct

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class StronglyConnectedComponents {
    int V;  //number of nodes
    ArrayList<Integer> adj[];   //adjacenty list
    int time;

    StronglyConnectedComponents(int v) {
        this.V = v;
        this.time = 0;
        this.adj = new ArrayList[v];
        Arrays.fill(adj, new ArrayList());  //adj list of v elements(arrayLists)

    }

    void addEdge(int v, int w) {
        adj[v].add(w);
    }

    void util(int u, int low[], int disc[], int stackMember[], Stack<Integer> st) {
        stackMember[u] = 1; //visited
        disc[u] = time;  //first time visiting time
        low[u] = time++;  //after update time +1
        st.push(u);  //dfs - take last added as first observal vertex

        for (Integer i : adj[u]) { //traversing adjacents of u
            if (disc[i] == -1) {
                util(i, low, disc, stackMember, st);
                if (low[u] > low[i]) low[u] = low[i];  //update If node v is not visited
            } else if (stackMember[i] != 0)  //if i is still in stack update value
            {
                if (low[u] > disc[i]) low[u] = disc[i];
            }
        }

        int w = -1;
        if (low[u] == disc[u]) {
            while (w != u) //while there is a path
            {

                w = (int) st.pop();
                stackMember[w] = 0;
                System.out.print(w + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }

    void SCC() {
        //first time all vertices has no parent, therefore fill with -1
        int disc[] = new int[V];
        Arrays.fill(disc, -1);
        int low[] = new int[V];
        Arrays.fill(low, -1);

        int stackMember[] = new int[V];
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
        //all vertices not visited filling
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            if (disc[i] == -1)//if not visited vertex
                util(i, low, disc, stackMember, st);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of nodes");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of edge");
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        m++;
        StronglyConnectedComponents g = new StronglyConnectedComponents(n);
        System.out.println("Enter the edges:");

        while (m-- > 0 && sc.hasNext()) {
            String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (input.length == 2) {
                g.addEdge(Integer.parseInt(input[0]), Integer.parseInt(input[1]));
            }
        }
        g.SCC();

    }
}
```

My input:

```
Enter the number of nodes
5
Enter the number of edge
5
Enter the edges:
1 0
0 2
2 1
0 3
3 4
```

my output:

```
4 3 1 2 0
```

Output should be like this:

```
0 1 2
3
4
```

I dont even know why there is mistake like this. I changed code from  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tarjan-algorithm-find-strongly-connected-components/ to my code, and added opportunity to input.
I asked about this and one friend said that "this is the output of both codes in the addEdge method after adding w, in your code w is added to all elements, and in the original only to the graph v"
but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line where you initialize the Lists for your adj-Array:

```
Arrays.fill(adj, new ArrayList());
```

---

When we take a look at the [Java-Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object)) we read the following for the method `public static void fill​(Object[] a, Object val)` from Arrays:

> *Assigns the specified Object reference to each element of the specified array of Objects.*

This means all of the entries in your adj-Array use the same list. In your example every node is at least one time on the right side, and therefore every node is in this one list.

---

When you replace the line above with a simple for loop to initialize the ArrayLists for the adj-Array, it should work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
  adj[i] = new ArrayList<>();
}
```